# WHERE NOT IN returns an empty set while it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, where-clause, notin

This query gives me back `90 826` rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices;
```

Now I check how many of these are present in another table having the same column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices
WHERE ClientID IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients
);
```

This gives back `90 736` rows, so `90` rows should not be in this other table. Lets check this out to be sure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices
WHERE ClientID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients
);
```

But this gives me back an empty set, `0` rows. This shouldn't be right, so I go further, trying this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM v_keszulekek
WHERE ClientID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices
    WHERE ClientID IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients
    )
);
```

This one gives me back the `90` rows indeed, but the first version should have worked as well in my opinion.

Clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to the strange world of NULL

Comment: Add a condition **WHERE CLIENTID IS NOT NULL** along with CLIENTID NOT IN condition

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices WHERE *ClientID IS NOT NULL AND** ClientID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients **WHERE ClientID IS NOT NULL** );

Comment: Show output of `show create table devices` and `show create table patients`.

Comment: Indeed `SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients` returned `NULL` as well as one of the values. Is there some comparison with the `NULL` value going on in the background?

Comment: @Strawberry Not strange, I would say, but misunderstood. Null is not a value, and according to SQL means "missing data": i.e the data exists, it's just "we couldn't get it". Therefore `NOT IN` can never return true in the presence of a null since the checked value "may be there"; it may return false; but it can return `UNKNOWN` too -- that is a full blown valid return according to the SQL Standard since the beginning.

Comment: @Govind you should make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL is not a data-type and you cannot use any filter or clause IN, NOT IN etc. You have to explicitly exclude it using **IS NULL** OR **IS NOT NULL** condition. Here, you have to perform the below to get the intended output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM devices WHERE ClientID IS NOT NULL AND ClientID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM patients WHERE ClientID IS NOT NULL );
```